# trouble with writing hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

Hiya, I'm sort a newbie when it comes to hibernate so I'm going to try to ask my question as clearly as possible. I wanna execute following query as hibernate query .

```
 <sql-query name="updateINFO">
      update 
            info 
      set   
            status_id = 2 
      where 
            pid = :i    
 </sql-query>
```

Now i is a dynamic value, so sometimes I'll pass 1 sometimes 1000, actually I'll iterate trough list and do the query for every item in the list, you get my point. Now here is my part of java calling execution of this query ..

```
 for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
 {
     Query query = session.getNamedQuery("updateINFO").setParameter("pid", list.get(i));
 }
```

Is there something wrong with this approach ? thank you

I already have created list of type Long and I get list items from another query

```
List<Long> list = null;
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("endDateChecker");
list = query.list();
```

here is my method :

```
public List<Long> I need findItemByPIdEndDate() throws Exception {

                List<Long> list = null;

                try{
                        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

                        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("endDateChecker");
                        list =  query.list();

                        for (Long listItem : list) {
                        Query query1 = session.getNamedQuery("updateINFO")
                        .setParameter("in",listItem);
        }



                }catch (HibernateException e){
                        throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
                }

                return list;
    }
```

Comment: Just edited my answer, as you can see, you are passing a Long instead of a Collection. you dont need to iterate anymore, just pass the list variable instead of all Longs in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use setParameterList:

```
 <sql-query name="updateINFO">


update info  set status_id = 2 where pid in (:parameters)

 </sql-query>
```

`public List <Long> findItemByPIdEndDate() throws Exception {`

```
List<Long> list = null;

    try{
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("endDateChecker");
        list =  query.list();


        Query query1 = session.getNamedQuery("updateINFO")
                    .setParameterList("parameters",list);

        query1.executeUpdate();



    }catch (HibernateException e){
        throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I've tried setParameterList and it gives me compile error, since my list is long type.

Comment: You cant create a primitive type Collection. use the Long class instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what do I need to do with that but here is the compile error "The method setParameterList(String, Collection) in the type Query is not applicable for the arguments (String, Long)"

Comment: Oh i see what you are doing, you have to pass your list as an argument to the set parameter list.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: well the error you're getting says you're passing a Long instead of a Collection.

Comment: Could you show me how exactly you are calling the setParameterList method?

Comment: I'm trying to build it and run .. I'll get back to you

Comment: Hmm its not working, and its not trowing any exeptions, I just added a syso line to print out hellou when it executes .. it executes but for some twister weird reason I have no idea of .. its not working , anymore ideas ?

Comment: Just like ammoQ said, you also forgot to call query1.executeUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

From your original question:

```
 for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
 {
     Query query = session.getNamedQuery("updateINFO").setParameter("pid", list.get(i));
 }
```

I think you forgot a call to the `query.executeUpdate()` method...

Comment: Thank you ammoQ .. I had to accept marco's solution .. but yours was final part of the puzzle .

Comment: Gandalf: sure, it's more an additional hint than the "answer" to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble using the NHibernate Query Language, they offer an alternative known as [Criteria Querying](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-criteria). The API allows you to build your query strings more dynamically and the is also more extensible than HQL. Give it a shot and see if it suits your needs.